# no output from python class method

Tags: python-3.x

```
class animal:

    def __init__(self,name,tag):

        self.name = name
        self.tag = tag

    def build(self):

        return f"{self.name} is a {self.tag}"

class insect(animal):
    pass


animal1 = animal("Cow","4 legs,2 horns")
insect1 = insect("Spyder","8legs, small sized")

animal1.build()
insect1.build()
```

after implementing this script I am not getting any output please check it.
but instead of return if given print function the output is shown

Comment: well, if you `print("foo")`, you print "foo", and if you `return "foo"`, you return "foo". what do you want to do? alternatively, you could do `print(animal1.build())` to get the same effect as printing from within you function

Answer (score 1):

Because your class used return, not print:

```
print(animal1.build())
print(insect1.build())
```

Output:

```
Cow is a 4 legs,2 horns
Spyder is a 8legs, small sized
```